# auto-increment an specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server, increment

I need to increment a column named Sequencia each Sequencia depends on CedenteID, Ano and Periodo to be incremented. This is what I use:

```
select @Seq = isnull(Sequencia, 0) + 1
from T041_NossoNumero
where CedenteID = @CedenteID
and Ano = @Ano
and Periodo = @Periodo      

update T041_NossoNumero
set Sequencia = @Seq
where CedenteID = @CedenteID
and Ano = @Ano
and Periodo = @Periodo
```

But, this code permits that I can have duplicate Sequencia if I execute it at the same time. I would like advice on what I should do instead of using update +1

What I have:

- CedenteID(PK/FK)
- Ano(PK)
- Periodo(PK)

```
  |CedenteID|Ano   |Periodo|Sequencia|
  |         |      |       |         |
  |392      |2016  |1      |37382    |
  |392      |2016  |2      |17351    |
```

What I need if:

- CedenteID = 392
- Ano = 2016
- Periodo = 2

```
 |CedenteID|Ano |Periodo|Sequencia|
 |         |    |       |         |
 |392      |2016|      1|    37382|
 |392      |2016|      2|    17352|
```

Comment: Do you have an identity column on that table?

Comment: So, two calls are submitted simultaneously, and you need it to be updated only once (+1, not +1 +1)? If so, how do you identify "simultaneous" vs "sequential" calls?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "automatically" increment by design a column is to use an Identity like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
    (
    sequence int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
```

But this will not work for you since you need it to increment only if all the other fields are the same.
This means the increment has to be done application-side.
Make sure you use a single transaction to do this because synchronisation problems may occur otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

By using transaction you can make sure you will not have duplicate in concurrent calls, but it may cause performance issues for your system.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    select @Seq = isnull(Sequencia, 0) + 1
    from T041_NossoNumero
    where CedenteID = @CedenteID
    and Ano = @Ano
    and Periodo = @Periodo      

    update T041_NossoNumero
    set Sequencia = @Seq
    where CedenteID = @CedenteID
    and Ano = @Ano
    and Periodo = @Periodo

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    THROW
END CATCH
```

Comment: I tried it before and allowed the same sequencia when I executed it in concurrent calls

Comment: You are violating the first rule of transactions by this comment.
In this code the table 'T041_NossoNumero' will be locked until the transaction will be committed, means there is no possibility to have the duplicate sequence number, unless you use the 'NOLOCK' keyword in your select.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but couldn't you use

```
UPDATE T041_NossoNumero
 set Sequencia = isnull(Sequencia, 0) + 1
 where CedenteID = @CedenteID
  and Ano = @Ano
  and Periodo = @Periodo
```

?

Comment: No, because of duplicate in concurrent calls.